# Sufficient and Necessary

Tags: logic

There is a watch you’d like to buy. It costs $100. Each of the following statements tells you something that is sufficient but not necessary, necessary but not sufficient, or both sufficient and necessary in order for you to purchase the watch. Consider each statement and label it accordingly.

You have at least $50

You have exactly $100

You have $400

You have at least $100

Answer (score 0):

1. Is necessary but not sufficient.  The watch cost $100.  It's necessary to have at least 50, but not sufficient.
2. Sufficient but not necessary.
3. Sufficient but not necessary.  You have $400 which is more than you need.
4. Sufficient and necessary.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I came up with as well.

Comment: As I look at it again, I believe that #2 should be sufficient but not necessary.  It is not necessary that you have exactly $100.  It is necessary that you have AT LEAST 100 though.  I will edit